# OpenCart 1.5.6.4 handle click event on checkout.tpl (new shipping-method with input select)

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, opencart

I edited in OpenCart 1.5.6.4 file catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/checkout.tpl to try to handle click event in my new shipping method with select element. I need after click on select element #bmat_data to be checked radio button with id #bmat.bmat.

this part of code is loading to checkout.tpl via ajax from catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/shipping_method.tpl

```
<div id="shipping-method">
  <div class="checkout-heading">Step 4: Shipping</div>
  <div class="checkout-content">
    ...
    <tr class="highlight">
     <td><input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="bmat.bmat" id="bmat.bmat"></td>
     <td>
       <label for="bmat.bmat">BMat</label>
       <select name="bmat_data" id="bmat_data">
         <option value="0">---</option>
         <option value="1">A</option>
         <option value="2">B</option>
       </select>
     </td>
     <td style="align:right;"><label for="bmat.bmat">some price</label></td>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

In file checkout.tpl after line starts with `<script type="text/javascript"><!--` I inserted this jquery code to handle it.

```
$('#bmat_data').click( function() {
    $('#bmat\\.bmat').prop('checked',true);
});
```

After click on select element radio button is not checked and I can't solve why. If I write simmilar code in separate file it works, but in this checkout.tpl file in OC not.
Can somebody help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I try another way insert jquery code directly into select element and it work. Does anybody know why it's working this way and with previous not?

```
<select name="bmat_data" id="bmat_data" onclick="$('input#bmat\\.bmat').prop('checked', true);">
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. Elements I would like handle did not exist at moment when the checkout.tpl is loaded (only base structure). These elemets are injected via ajax later. When I move jquery code to injected file shipping_method.tpl it works correctly.

```
<div id="shipping-method">
  <div class="checkout-heading">Step 4: Shipping</div>
  <div class="checkout-content">
    ...
    <tr class="highlight">
     <td><input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="bmat.bmat" id="bmat.bmat"></td>
     <td>
       <label for="bmat.bmat">BMat</label>
       <select name="bmat_data" id="bmat_data">
         <option value="0">---</option>
         <option value="1">A</option>
         <option value="2">B</option>
       </select>
     </td>
     <td style="align:right;"><label for="bmat.bmat">some price</label></td>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $('#bmat_data').click( function() {
      $('#bmat\\.bmat').prop('checked',true);
  });
</script>
});
```